# Property "somemethod" does not exist on type 'typeof "className"

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, axios, typescript2.0

I am getting a "Property 'searchStaff' does not exist on type 'typeof UserService'." error in my editor when I try to use this api service class. PS. I am new to typescript.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

class UserService {
  public searchStaff(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(axios.get("./staffs/search"));
  }
}

export default new UserService();
```

I am trying to get data from this class.

```
const result = UserService.searchStaff();
```

Comment: How are you importing `UserService` in the second file? Can you post that?

Comment: import UserService from "../services/UserService";

Comment: I have just tested it and it works fine for me. Something is missing here. Can you post the second file?

Comment: why is there a `new` on your export statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly put `export` or `export default` in your declaration. So you can do:

```
export class UserService {
```

}

or

```
export default class UserService {
```

}

You can find the different methods of using modules for typescript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Also, looking at this line of code,  `const result = UserService.searchStaff();` are you instantiating UserService? If not, then you have to declare `searchStaff` as `static`.

Comment: Thank you, static did it for me and I could search the documentation and learn why.

Comment: I needed `static` too. Thanks.